# Linq group by one multiple properties

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have a XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<Cars>
    <Car>
        <Id>1</Id>
        <Color>Blue</Color>
        <Price>2000</Price>
    </Car>
    <Car>
        <Id>2</Id>
        <Color>Blue</Color>
        <Price>2000</Price>
    </Car>
    <Car>
        <Id>3</Id>
        <Color>Blue</Color>
        <Price>3000</Price>
    </Car>
    <Car>
        <Id>4</Id>
        <Color>Green</Color>
        <Price>2000</Price>
    </Car>
    <Car>
        <Id>5</Id>
        <Color>Green</Color>
        <Price>3000</Price>
    </Car>
</Cars>
```

And an associated class :

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Cars")]
public class Cars        
{            
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Car")]
    public List<Car> Car { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Color { get; set; }

    public string Price { get; set; }
}
```

I want to group the cars by the Color and Price and have a List with group result.

I do :

```
Cars cars = Dezerialise<Cars>(MyXmlFile);

var group =
from c in d.Car
group c by new
{
    c.Color,
    c.Price,
} into gcs
select new Car()
{
    Color = gcs.Key.Color,
    Price = gcs.Key.Price,
};
```

But I have  : [image: Result]

I want in each index of my result a List of Car matching : group[0] = List with two car , group[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbqdC.jpg) = List with one car etc etc

Answer (score 0):

You also need to project the group result like:

```
var group =
from c in d.Car
group c by new
{
    c.Color,
    c.Price,
} into gcs
select new Cars()
{
  Car =  gcs.ToList()
};
```

It will give you records like :

[image]

Using Lambda Expression:

```
var group = d.Car.GroupBy(c=> new
                  {
                     c.Color,
                     c.Price
                   })
                 .Select(gcs=> new Cars()
                   {
                     Car =  gcs.ToList()
                   });
```

Comment: you have to project again using SelectMany for that

Comment: do you means single ``List<Car>`` ? if that's the case why you are gouping?

Comment: like : ``var Carrs = group.SelectMany(x => x.Car);``

Comment: i will add the lambda expression way as well

Comment: Thx !! Is it possible to select directly a new List<Car> ?

Comment: can you elaborate more what you are asking, or you can ask a new question